# Excel VBA Output String If Search Not Found

Tags: excel, vba

My code currently searches through Sheet1 and copies rows into Sheet2 if it matches the array of strings in strSearch. How can I make it so that it outputs "No Search Found" as a row on Sheet2 if there are no rows that contain the strSearch?

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim firstRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs2 As Long
Dim searchColumnWs1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim check As Variant
Dim strSearch As Variant
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")


Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
With ws2
lastRowWs1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastRowWs2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
firstRowWs1 = 1
searchColumnWs1 = 10
strSearch = Array("John", "Jim")

For i = firstRowWs1 To lastRowWs1
    For Each check In strSearch
        If check = ws1.Cells(i, searchColumnWs1).Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy (ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1))
            ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1).Columns("A:B").Insert xlToRight
            lastRowWs2 = lastRowWs2 + 1
            ws1.Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next check
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Set a boolean variable to true if there is a match, after the loop if its false then ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1).Cells(1).Value = "No match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of whether or not you found matches, and add the text after your loop.

Eg:

```
Dim foundMatches as Boolean
foundMatches = False

For i = firstRowWs1 To lastRowWs1
    For Each check In strSearch
        If check = ws1.Cells(i, searchColumnWs1).Value Then
            foundMatches = True
            ... etc
        End If
    Next check
Next i

If Not foundMatches then
  ' print "no rows found" somewhere
end if
```